# Unimplemented Javascript primitive caml_pure_js_expr (again)

Tags: ocaml, js-of-ocaml, ocsigen

I have a project in OCaml that could be compiled in Ubuntu long time ago. Today, I want to pick up the project and try to compile it in `macOS Mojave 10.14.2`.

`ocaml --version` returns `The OCaml toplevel, version 4.07.1`, `js_of_ocaml --version` returns `3.3.0`, `npm --version` returns `6.7.0`, `node --version` returns `v8.9.3`.

`makefile` works fine and generates `analyze`. But `./analyze test.ev` returns `Unimplemented Javascript primitive caml_pure_js_expr!`.

Does anyone know where may be the problem?

**Edit 1:**

As my `analyze` is big, I test a small example that could reproduce the error. I write `cubes.ml` as follows:

```
let () =
  let oneArgument (a: int) = a + 100 in
  Js_of_ocaml.Js.Unsafe.global##.jsOneArgument := Js_of_ocaml.Js.wrap_callback oneArgument;
  print_string "hello\n";
  exit 0
```

The following two commands generate well `T`:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -g -package js_of_ocaml.ppx -linkpkg cubes.ml -o T
js_of_ocaml --debuginfo --sourcemap --pretty T -o cubes.js
```

`node cubes.js` returns well `hello`, however `./T` returns `Unimplemented Javascript primitive caml_pure_js_expr!`

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question, we have no idea about your tool chain, your build script, your code, and what this `analyze` script does. None of this is particularly standard.

Comment: I just posted a small example that reproduces the problem...

Comment: `T` uses primitives to access javascript properties (as should be obvious by the code). You can't run it natively, you can only run the javascript code.